# Switching between multiple UITableView with VoiceOver causes crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, voiceover

I have a `UIViewController` with the following view hierarchy:

```
    UIView (root of UIViewController)
      |__________
      |          |
UITableView(A)  UIView (overlay view)
            ____|_______
           |            |
       UITableView(B)  UITableView(C)
```

None of the `UITableViews` are shown simultaneously – I simply switch between them for various reasons: one is for normal items, one is used for searching results, etc.

I'm getting this crash, somewhat consistently, by turning on `VoiceOver`, causing `UITableView` B to appear, dismissing it, and then navigating through accessibility items in `UITableView` A.

Here's the call stack:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x00000001954a7bd0 objc_msgSend + 16
1  UIKit                          0x000000018317ea68 -[UITableViewCellAccessibility _accessibilityReuseChildren:forMockParent:] + 496
2  UIKit                          0x000000018318f28c -[UITableViewCellAccessibilityElement tableViewCell] + 260
3  UIKit                          0x000000018318fcac -[UITableViewCellAccessibilityElement isAccessibilityElement] + 24
4  UIAccessibility                0x0000000191c2c030 _appendChildrenToArrayStartingAtIndexWithChildren + 352
5  UIAccessibility                0x0000000191c2bd04 _addAXElementsToArrayFromObject + 1620
6  UIAccessibility                0x0000000191c2b680 _appendVendedAXElementsFromUIElements + 288
7  UIAccessibility                0x0000000191c2b53c _createAXUIElementsFromUIElements + 160
8  UIAccessibility                0x0000000191c2a3cc _copyParameterizedAttributeValueCallback + 208
9  AXRuntime                      0x000000018a5f4a30 _AXXMIGCopyParameterizedAttributeValue + 256
10 AXRuntime                      0x000000018a5f0850 _XCopyParameterizedAttributeValue + 412
11 AXRuntime                      0x000000018a5fbbc0 mshMIGPerform + 272
12 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000184cf6200 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
13 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000184cf6160 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 436
14 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000184cf40e0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1640
15 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000184c210a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
16 GraphicsServices               0x000000018ddc35a4 GSEventRunModal + 168
17 UIKit                          0x00000001895563c0 UIApplicationMain + 1488
18 Stack Exchange                 0x000000010018dbe4 main (main.m:16)
19 libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000195b02a08 start + 4
```

The crashing error is:

`[UITableTextAccessibilityElement accessibilityContainer] message sent to deallocated instance`

I'm running on `iOS` 8.1.2.

Clearly, this has something to do with `VoiceOver`, or rather, the way `UIAccessibility` is navigating through its accessibility elements, trying to access a deallocated object. I've tried posting accessibility notifications  such as `UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification` and `UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification` after hiding and showing the `UITableView`s to let the `accessibility` know that the screen has changed, but haven't had any luck.

My `UITableView`s A and C also have some extra subviews, used as refresh/load more controls, but even removing these isn't helping.

**Update:** I am also getting these warnings when using `VoiceOver` to tap on a `UITextField` which is a subview of `UITableView`(a) `headerView` property:

```
**** Accessibility: Could not find a valid index for <SESearchBar: 0x16a03150; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = ''; layer = <CALayer: 0x16a02fc0>> in -[UITableView indexOfAccessibilityElement:]
|warning| **** Accessibility: Could not find where <SESearchBar: 0x16a03150; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = ''; layer = <CALayer: 0x16a02fc0>> starts. Was its parent [<UITableView: 0x16208a00; frame = (0 0; 320 504); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x16b4a8c0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x16b49750>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 1800}>] set correctly or did it disappear?
```

Comment: Do you see console messages that describe anything about an error when it crashes?  If you set zombies on in your scheme, do you get a better error message about the target of objc_msgSend?

Comment: @PhillipMills I've added some console warnings in the question. And I do have zombies turned on, so that's the best we've got.

Comment: Are you using standard VoiceOver implementation for the tableView cells? Such as assigning the accessibilityLabel on the cell itself? Or something more custom with say grouping of the cell's sub-views? Try this - after the screen does change, call `[self.tableView reloadData]` and then post the notification that the screen/layout changed. If you can post some code you're using, that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in my project. After a few hours of debugging I found what the issue has been. It turns out that VoiceOver crashed due to some empty (empty as in without any labels/images/etc.) table view cells (I use empty cells as as additional spacing separators around the selected cell in a specific section). After I removed the accessibility elements in those cells the crashes also disappeared... maybe this helps in your case too.

```
- (NSInteger)accessibilityElementCount {
    return 0;
}

- (NSArray *)accessibilityElements {
    return nil;
}
```